# How to prove this topology equality?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $(A,\tau_A)$ is the subspace of $(X,\tau)$, show that for all $B\in 2^A$ the following relationship holds:
$$\text{int}B=\text{int}_A B\cap \text{int} A.$$
Here subtopology $\tau_A$ is defined as follows: $V\in\tau_A$ if there exists some $U\in\tau$ such that $V=U\cap A$.  And $\text{int}$ denotes the interior of a set, which is defined as the union of every open subset it contains.

So here I go. From definitions
$$\text{RHS}=\text{int}A\cap (\bigcup_{C\subset B,C\in\tau_A}C)=\text{int}A\cap (\bigcup_{C^*\cap A\subset B,C^*\in\tau}(C^*\cap A))=(\bigcup_{C^*\cap A\subset B,C^*\in\tau}(C^*\cap \text{int}A)).$$
Don't know what to do next. Most probably I'm on the wrong track.

So I really need help from you guys now. Clues and complete answers are both appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B\subset A\implies Int (B)\subset Int (A),$ we have $$Int (B)=Int_A (B)\cap Int(A)\iff Int (B)=Int_A(B)\cap Int(A)\cap Int(B)=$$ $$=Int_A(B)\cap Int(B).$$  Since $Int_A(B)\cap Int (B)\subset Int (B),$ it suffices to prove that $Int_A(B)\cap Int (B)\supset Int (B),$ equivalently that $Int_A(B)\supset Int (B).$

For this, observe that $Int (B)\in \tau$ and $Int (B)\subset B\subset A\;$, so $Int (B)\in \tau_A.$ Any member of $\tau_A$ that is a subset of $B$ is a subset of $Int_A(B)$, by def'n of $Int_A(B),$ so  $Int (B)\subset Int_A(B).$

Comment: Thanks. This is really straightforward and convincing.

Comment: I'm not completely convinced yet. :-) Why is the first step $$Int(B) = Int_A(B) \cap Int(A) \;\iff\; Int(B) = Int_A(B) \cap Int(A) \cap Int(B)$$ allowed?  The only reason I can see is $\;Int_A(B) \subset Int(B)\;$, or equivalently $\;Int_A(B) = Int_A(B) \cap Int(B)\;$.

Comment: For completeness: if I understand correctly, this answer uses the following rules about $\;Int\;$: for every $\;C,D \subset X\;$,
$$
Int(C) \subset C
\\
Int(C) \in \tau
\\
C \subset D \;\implies\; Int(C) \subset Int(D)
\\
Int_A(B) \subset Int(B)
$$ (where the last one is the one I asked about in my previous comment).

Comment: @MarnixKlooster . Your first comment raises a good point,  The assertion $Int_A(B)\cap Int(B)=Int(B)\implies Int_A(B)\cap Int(A)=Int(B)$   $does$ depend on $Int_A(B)\subset Int(B)$, which I only proved in my last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

$$
A^o\cap (\bigcup_{C\subset B,C\in\tau_A}C)=A^o\cap (\bigcup_{C\subset B\cap A}C)=\bigcup_{C\subset B\cap A}(A^o\cap C)
$$
Since for any open set $C\subset B\cap A$ and $B\subset A$, there is 
$$
C\subset (B\cap A)^o\subset A^o
$$
So $A^o\cap C=C$. And 
$$
\bigcup_{C\subset B\cap A}(A^o\cap C)=\bigcup_{C\subset B}C=B^o
$$

Comment: Do your $\text{int}$s all refer to interior under $\tau$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @hermes Could you please clarify how, in your first step, you get from $$\bigcup_{C \subset B, C \in \tau_A} C$$ to $$\bigcup_{C^* \subset B \cap A, C^* \in \tau} C^*$$?

Comment: @hermes I'm sorry, but I don't understand how that explains your first step. From the definitions of $\;\text{int}\;$ $$
\text{int}_Z V \;=\; \bigcup_{C \subset V, C \in \tau_Z} C
$$ and of subtopology $$\tau_A \;=\; \{ C^* \cap A \mid C^* \in \tau\}$$ I can only get to the OP's $$\text{int}_A B \;=\; \bigcup_{C^* \cap A \subset B, C^* \in \tau} (C^* \cap A)$$  Could you perhaps spell out some more the set theory steps you are using in that first step?